# How to call Makefile located in other directory?

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

I am trying to do this:

I want to call a make (`Makefile` exists in some other directory, `abc` path can be used) from a shell script located in a different directory. How do I do this?

Since shell scripting does not allow me to `cd` into the `Makefile` directory and execute `make`, how can I write the shell command (by giving path to the `Makefile` to be executed) to execute `make`?

Comment: What do you mean by `Shell scripting does not allow me to 'cd' into the make file directory`?  Sure it does: `cd /p/a/t/h && make` works just fine.

Comment: Hello William, Thanks for your reply. for some reason, I was not able to use the cd command in the shell script. its gives an error.. this is the syntax i used iwthin the shell script: cd <path>

Answer (score 35, accepted):

GNU `make` accepts many [options](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary), notably `-C` to change directory before running, and `-f` for giving the `Makefile` to follow.

Combine them appropriately.

Consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to ease debugging (notably with `-x`) of `Makefile` related issues. With GNU make version 4 or better, also use `make --trace`...

You could have your own executable shell script (e.g. in your `$HOME/bin/` which would be in your `$PATH`) which uses both `cd` and `make`).

You could consider other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools ([ninja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_(build_system)) perhaps)

Read also P.Miller's paper [*Recursive Make considered harmful*](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much! I shall look at these alternatives!

Comment: How do i call a C program (instead of make) which exists in other directory? I have the .o file in the other directory.

Comment: You should ask another question. You first need to *compile* your *C* program into an executable, and then you run that executable, perhaps by giving its full path. Notice that `*.o` files are *not* executable binaries.

Comment: Thanks Basile! I was able to do this as well.