# Is there a variable to set so that "make" command searches for makefiles

Tags: makefile

Is there a variable to set, so that `make` command searches for makefiles in other directories rather than only searching for makefiles in the current working directory?

**Update**: The scenario is like this, in our project we have a script which mostly defines & sets some of environment variables. Then a make is given in the root folder (to build) which doesn't have a makefile. Hence, I don't think "-c" or other make options can help in this.
I found, after some investigation, that makefile is in internal folders and being invoked. So, my question is are there any environmental varibles which makes the "make" command to search for makefiles in that specified directories (by the environment variable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Makefile located in other directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436002/how-to-call-makefile-located-in-other-directory)

Comment: @IanAuld Updated my question

Comment: Is the answer in this question useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081372/linux-bash-script-to-run-make-in-all-subdirectories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not possible to have make search for makefiles in a different directory than the one it was started in (or switched to due to the `-C` option, for GNU make) by default.

You have two options: one is to use the `-f` option as above.

The other is to set the `MAKEFILES` variable to the list of makefiles you want read in before you invoke `make`.  Note this must be the actual files you want read in, not just the directory that contains them.  The downside of this is that the default target will never be taken from these makefiles: see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html which means you'll need to always specify the target you want to build on the command line.

Comment: **MAKEFILES** is the one, the script is setting the MAKEFILES to the location of internal directory structure which has my makefile.

Answer (score 0):

For root makefile you have to specific the file name, use

```
make -f mymakefiledir/makefile
```

for nested makefile, there is `make -I MyMakefileDir`

$man make

```
-f file, --file=file, --makefile=FILE
                Use file as a makefile.

-I dir, --include-dir=dir
                Specifies  a  directory  dir to search for included makefiles.  If
                several -I options are used to specify  several  directories,  the
                directories are searched in the order specified.  Unlike the argu‐
                ments to other flags of make, directories given with -I flags  may
                come directly after the flag: -Idir is allowed, as well as -I dir.
                This syntax is allowed for compatibility with the C preprocessor's
                -I flag.
```

Comment: Updated the question for my specific scenario, where options in make may not help.

Comment: Imagine your environment variable is MyMakefileDir, can u just define a new variable using $export MyMakefile = $MyMakefileDir/makefile, and then make -f $MyMakefile?

Comment: If your environment variable include multiple paths, u can use sed to split them. `for i in \`echo $PATH | sed "s/:/ /g"\`
do MyMakefile = $i/makefile
make -f $MyMakefile
done`

Answer (score 0):

According to manpage of GNU make.

```
If no -f option is present, make will look for the makefiles,GNUmakefile, 
makefile, and Makefile, in that order.
```

There are no environmental variables make will refer for searching Makefile in other directory. Why not create a new makefile in root folder to call your makefile in internal folders?